# What type of headphone connector is this?

Tags: connector, cables, headphones

I got a pair of Onkyo headphones as a gift a while ago, and now one of the connectors on the cable broke (the red one in the picture).

What type of cable connector is this?  Searching the Onkyo website and amazon didn't get me anywhere.  What do I look for to find a replacement regardless of the manufacturer?

[image]
[image]

Comment: A very inconvenient one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for a format specification starting with the manufacturer of the product:
From [the vendor you mentioned](http://www.intl.onkyo.com/whats_new/2013_0101.html)

> Onkyo is offering the ES-HF300 with a 6N oxygen-free copper cable encased in clear elastomer, providing almost perfect conductivity while keeping touch noise to a minimum. Gold-plated **MMCX connectors** and mini-stereo plug reflect the highest build standards.

A quick read that might explain more about the format and its history reveals an industry specification:
From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMCX_connector)

> They conform to the **European CECC 22000** specification.

Using a search engine with the connector format and the device type produces many potential matches for the device in question (MMCX connector and headphones):
From [some vendor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011UC78NI), this appears to be an example of a viable replacement (by visual inspection).

That should get you going.